# replacing spaces and newlines with commas

Tags: php, regex

In my preg_replace RegEx here

```
$string = preg_replace('~[^[:alnum:],]*,[^[:alnum:]]*~', ',', $string);
```

i've been trying to split words from each other with commas, and it worked, But then i tried for a string like

```
x
y
z
```

and

```
x y z
```

to replace the whitespaces and newlines with so i wrote the tried using `[[:space:]]` and `[[:blank:]]` but they're more of solving whitespaces, but not newlines,

How to handle the new lines? i tried using my old replacement `/[\s,]+/` for newlines and whitespaces, But still no effect, I know i can go two queries like

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\s,]+/', ',', $string);
$string = preg_replace('~[^[:alnum:],]*,[^[:alnum:]]*~', ',', $string);
```

but i prefer merging them into one `RegEx` for performance.

Comment: post the `$string` content, cause your regex requires `,`. There's no comma in your current string `x y z`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew now that solved it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The problem that i actually thought that `|` can only be used for matching one of two parts `(a|b)`. You actually enlightend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
preg_replace("'/[^[:alnum:],]*,[^[:alnum:]]*|[\s,]+/'", ",", $string);
```

It will replace all spaces and new lines with a `,` comma.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your right, forgot to add the substitution. However, OP should post all relevant information in this question.

Comment: @mega6382 OP already tried that second code. It didn't work for them. Look at their question